Does the Rogue's Evasion cost a reaction?
My 12th-level rogue was attacked by an opponent with a pike and then (bonus action) Flame Burst. DM said I could use Uncanny Dodge (a reaction) to halve the pike damage, but even though I saved on the Dex saving throw, I couldn't use Evasion to remove all damage from the Flame Burst.
2014 rules states Uncanny Dodge is a reaction, but nothing says Evasion is a reaction.

Somewhat related: Does Evasion allow half damage even when unconscious?, since one can't take reactions while unconscious

Evasion has no cost. It is always on.
The rules for Evasion are quite clear:

When you are subjected to an effect that allows you to make a Dexterity saving throw to take only half damage, you instead take no damage if you succeed on the saving throw, and only half damage if you fail.

It has no action cost. Its effect happens when it says it happens, which is "When you are subjected to an effect that allows you to make a Dexterity saving throw to take only half damage". Checking the text of what I am assuming Kansaldi Fire-Eyes' Flame Burst (wields a pike, only published creature with a Flame Burst action), we see:

[...] The target must make a DC 16 Dexterity saving throw.[...]On a successful save, the target takes half as much damage and doesn’t catch fire.

So this damage is eligible for being reduced via Evasion. Your DM may have had another reason for the way they ruled, or they may have made mistake. Either is okay, just have a nice conversation about it.

Thomas,
Thank you for your explanation. I did compromised with the DM, taking the lesser of the two damage values. (It was my first damage in the combat, after dealing a great deal of damage to the opponent. And, yes, it was Kansaldi Fire-Eyes.)

"Either is okay, just have a nice conversation about it." Love this.

"Your DM may have had another reason" is key here. The DM is not just a computer running a video game, but has the ability to decide when bending rules as written is best for a scene or circumstance. It's a delicate balance that relies on earning player trust and not abusing it, but it isn't automatically wrong. Thus the "nice conversation", to let them know your expectations and give them a chance to either explain or adjust, whatever best benefits the table.

I wouldn't be surprised if the DM's ruling came from a place of 'a skill that "evades" without using anything in the action system to actually move? That can't be right...'.
